# Insert One Table to Another Table with out one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table Name `Test` Fields Are `id Name age city`

```
 | ID   |   NAME    |  AGE    |  CITY   |
 |  1   | raja      |  20     |  abc    |
 |  2   | raju      |  32     |  abcd   |
```

ID is `Primary key`.

Now i want insert 3 entry duplicate of 2 entry with id no 3. with out specifying column name.

Sample Entry :

```
|  3  | raju | 32  | abcd |
```

Like:

```
 insert into Test select 3,(get value with out id and don't specify the columns name) from test where id=2
```

It is possible?. If its possible how to do this or Tell any feasible solution?

Version : **Postgresql 9.3**

Comment: Why don't you want to specify the columns?

Comment: @FilipeSilva Because my case is doesn't need specifying the column name

Comment: Just wanted to know if your reason of not specifying them could be worked out. If you know you can't specify them, and your column is not auto_incremented, i can't help you sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the id column is also AUTO INCREMENT.

```
INSERT INTO Test SELECT Name, age, city FROM test WHERE id=2
```

**EDIT**

You should be able to do it also like this since your id column is PRIMARY KEY and AUTO INCREMENT:

```
INSERT INTO Test(Name, age, city) SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=2
```

Comment: I don't want to specify the columns name like select name,age,city like that.

Comment: id not auto increment. if do like that its collapsed my project. And your second query return a `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "id"`

Comment: I've edited my second query. It would work if your id column was auto increment, but in this case I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But Sorry i don't want specifying columns name in that query in all possible. Because my case like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add without specifying any column name like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_name like you have (Test)
VALUES(val1, val2, val3,...);

INSERT INTO Test
VALUES(3, raju, abcd);
```